# Changing .csv file from UTF-16 to UTF-8 deletes file data

Tags: unix, csv, utf-8

I tried changing character set of .csv file from UTF-16 to UTF-8 using the unix command

```
iconv -f utf-16le -t UTF-8//TRANSLIT <input file> -o <output file>
```

After running word count command, the content of file reduced to 466 lines from 5600 lines originally.

Comment: Are you sure your word count command understands UTF-16 and counts lines correctly in the first place?

Comment: Are you sure the input was UTF-16?

Comment: Better post a small sample file.